# How many alphanumeric charecters can be embedded in a QR Code?

Tags: character-encoding, qr-code, zxing, alphanumeric, zbar-sdk

As per the Wiki below

[QRC Storage Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage)

the maximum number of alphanumeric charecters that can be stored is 4,296. But while trying it out, I'm unable to proceed for more than approx 2220 charecters at an error correction level of L.

Is alphanumeric charecters not the same numeric charecters. Do "123", "XYZ" and "AB%" not all contain "Three" charecters?

Comment: AFIK it is possible to encode so much data like you want. The problem is just that if the QR code is too big you cannot scan it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I'm not sure what use is a QRC that has a large amount of data embedded in it but can't be scanned later :(

Comment: @rekire no there are certainly limits. See the link posted right there above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max is 4296 if you are in alphanumeric mode. To do that you can only use the characters listed on the link you sent. Your examples are certainly all 3 characters, and fit the alphanumeric character set.

It is probably a problem with the encoder, or some other intermediate limitation, like the length of a URL you are sending to the encoder.

Comment: Thank you @Sean for the answer. So are =,<,> not alphanumeric charecters? I'm basically trying to embed XML data in a QRC.

Comment: Look at the link you posted -- no